# Не корректно отображается ScrollView

Tags: android, android-toolbar

Вот разметка:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<include
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    layout="@layout/app_bar"/>



<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/app_bar">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:id="@+id/detailedArticleTitle"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:padding="8dp"
           />
<com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
    android:id="@+id/detailedArticleImg"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:paddingRight="8dp"
    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:id="@+id/detailedArticleContent"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:textIsSelectable="true"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/ad_mob_banner_detail_activity"
    ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Разметка app_bar:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    app:theme="@style/MyCustomToolBarTheme"
    android:background="@color/primaryColor"
    android:paddingTop="0dp">
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

При запуске активности `TextView` c `Id = detailedArticleTitle` перекрывается `ToolBar`ом. Не могу понять в чем проблема. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а по вашему мнению, где он должен был бы показаться при такой разметке? Зачем здесь использовать `RelativeLayout` - хватило бы и вертикального `LinearLayout`. Все равно все по порядку идет

Comment: Cудя по разметке, он и есть первый в списке.

Comment: @pavlofff RelativeLayout использую что бы банер рекламный нормально отображался поверх текста. А для наглядности добавил скрин что у меня получается. Получается я не правильно выразился, не под `Toolbar`, а `Toolbar` накладывается на `ScrollView`

Comment: Вот теперь понятно в чем проблема. В будущем старайтесь оформлять вопросы так, чтобы у других людей было как можно меньше непонимания. Учитывайте, что они не видят и не знают о вопросе того, что знаете вы, а только то, что вы о нем сообщили.

Comment: Покажите разметку `app_bar` что ли .. у меня не воспроизводится проблема, если в `app_bar` только `toolbar`

Comment: @pavlofff добавил в вопрос.

Comment: Нет, у меня не получается воспроизвести вашу проблему. Попробуйте задать "классическую" высоту для `toolbar` - `android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"` и попробовать, что получится, если не задавать кастомную тему для тулбара.

Comment: @pavlofff попробовал не помогает. Будем копать дальше(

Answer (score 1):

В опции `android:layout_below` id должно быть без "+":

```
<ScrollView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_below="@id/app_bar">
```

т.к. "+" означает, что создается новый id:

> ID
>
> Any View object may have an integer ID associated with it, to uniquely
>   identify the View within the tree. When the application is compiled,
>   this ID is referenced as an integer, but the ID is typically assigned
>   in the layout XML file as a string, in the id attribute. This is an
>   XML attribute common to all View objects (defined by the View class)
>   and you will use it very often. The syntax for an ID, inside an XML
>   tag is:
>
> android:id="@+id/my_button"
>
> The at-symbol (@) at the beginning of the
>   string indicates that the XML parser should parse and expand the rest
>   of the ID string and identify it as an ID resource. **The plus-symbol
>   (+) means that this is a new resource name that must be created and
>   added to our resources (in the R.java file).** There are a number of
>   other ID resources that are offered by the Android framework. When
>   referencing an Android resource ID, you do not need the plus-symbol,
>   but must add the android package namespace, like so:
>
> android:id="@android:id/empty"

может быть он просто не находит ресурс app_bar? Ниже которого он должен быть расположен из-за того, что создается для него новый id?

Comment: Да тут ошибочка, исправил не помогло.

Comment: может быть в ScrollView сделать еще: android:layout_height="wrap_content"?

Comment: без результатов.

Comment: А если app_bar из разметки выкинуть (например, закомментировать) и заменить на обычное TextView?

Comment: Если убрать include все равно отображение начинается с картинки. самTextView спрятан(